How to fix KiteMatic install errors, gvfs-bin & python not installed?
I am trying to install KiteMatic on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS virtual machine. I am getting following errors:

I tried installing gvfs-bin, but got error as shown in screenshot.I tried instruction on this link to install gvfs-bin.
Python is already installed as can be seen from screenshot.

How do I fix this issue?
